# Leaflet - get bounds of all layers, not just vector

Tags: leaflet

I need to get the bounds of all layers in a Leaflet map, not just vector layers. For vectors, I add them to a `L.featureGroup`, which has the method `getBounds()`. How do I include raster layers as well?

Comment: What kind of raster layers do you use?

Comment: In the first instance, I'm using `L.imageOverlay`s.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the case of raster layers being `L.imageOverlay`'s, you must have instantiated them specifying the image bounds.

If for any reason you lost reference of these bounds, you can retrieve them using `myImageOverlay._bounds`.

We could even imagine extending the `L.ImageOverlay` class to include a `getBounds()` method, so that it becomes compatible when embedded in a Feature Group with the latter own `getBounds()` method:

```js
L.ImageOverlay.include({ // to be included in your script before instantiating image overlays.
    getBounds: function () {
        return this._bounds;
    }
});

var myImageOverlay = L.imageOverlay(imageUrl, bounds);

var myFeatureGroup = L.featureGroup([myImageOverlay]);

var myBounds = myFeatureGroup.getBounds();
```

Comment: This looks like a brilliant solution. I'll try it out.

Comment: Yes, that works perfectly (extending `L.ImageOverlay` with `.getBounds()`) - thanks so much.